# jQuery: Get value of selected radio group when name is an array?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a group of radio group like below and I am having problems getting the selected/checked value. I think is it because the name is an array. I renamed my id's to the same to see if I could do it that way but no luck.

```
<input type="radio" name="accounts[1][details][status]" value="1" id="status_1" />
<input type="radio" name="accounts[1][details][status]" value="2" id="status_1" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it. See jQuery docs on [escaping special characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$('input[name="accounts\\[1\\]\\[details\\]\\[status\\]"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work still when I add double backslashes.

Comment: Thank I got it working there was a missing \," and ]. Working code is $('input[name="accounts\\[1\\]\\[details\\]\\[status\\]"]:checked').val();

Comment: @Billy, Ha, sorry about that. I updated my question to fix syntax.

Comment: This is when jQuery lets you down.. `$("form").get(0).elements["accounts[1][details][status]"]` is perhaps easier to read...

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for :checked to get the one that is selected

```
<input type="radio" name="accounts[1][details][status]" value="1" class="status" />
<input type="radio" name="accounts[1][details][status]" value="2" class="status" />

jQuery: 

$(".status").change(function ()
{
    var checked_value = $(".status:checked").val();
});
```

Comment: The reason I've used a class is to avoid having to escape a lot of brackets.

Comment: I just edited to fix a typo/syntax error :) I agree with your version and find it much better than mine.

Comment: @Kevin I saw the edit and thanks for changing it. I was just commenting to explain why I'd gone with classes. Thanks